# View cv on same line as name of "Who you will work with" when no tag likes selected

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On jobs you have a section regarding tags you are interested in.  This will show up on the "Who you'll work with", like so:

[image]

This looks pretty good, unless you don't have any tag likes which the cv link stays on the same line as the employee name, not so nice:

[image]

Poor [zangief](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1RXDB_enUS591US591&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=zangief&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgVeLUz9U3MMowyTMzki4uKUpNLVFIy0zPKEktUjBSSM5ILEpMBrKLTzGCFRqbFZZnQNlGWel5ljBxwyyDXJg4yLBHjIcZuQVe_rgnLLWTcdKak9cYNzFyCfjk5xen5lQGpeYklqSmhOQLqXGxueaVZJZUCslw8UqBtRtmWWQZaTBIcXMhuEJlXNzBqSUh-b75KZlplULpQqlcnL6puUlAl_mnCUVwcTnn5-SkJpdk5ucJeXGpSCnoJ8MF9NMywXRiTjzCP0ALlLgIquIBABxB6MshAQAA) his cv is next to his name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report Jon, fixed!